# C# web api swagger integration

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a problem to integrate swagger ui with my web api, and i don't have any idee what is the problem.

When i call in the browser the swagger, the page `http://localhost:56381/swagger/ui/index` is like in this screenshot

[image: http://localhost:56381/swagger/ui/index]

In the SwaggerConfig.cs file i have this code:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

 namespace dummyNamespace
 {
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
       public static void Register()
      {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Test API"))
            .EnableSwaggerUi();

       }
    }
  }
```

I follow this tutorial: http://www.wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/ . But not working.

I don't now what is wrong with my configuratio.

I use .net framework 4.5.2, Web api 2.0 and Swashbuckle.5.5.3 version

Update:
When I call this url

```
http://localhost:56381/swagger/docs/v1
```

Return this image: 
[image: docs/v1]

Update1:

After i put this code in my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

Now the http://localhost:56381/swagger/ui/index  return this json:

```
  {
    "statusCode": 200
  }
```

Any idee how to make make http://localhost:56381/swagger/ui/index return this page: [image]

[image]

The page is from a test project.

Comment: Why do you belive that ?

Comment: Try to click link, it;s a png file. The link is the description of png

Comment: @MegaTron My Startup.cs is in the root of my project. and contain:            `code` public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }

Comment: @MegaTron Sorry. Bad link. This is the correct one: http://www.wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/. Multiple tabs in chrome and bad copy paste.

Comment: Can you post your Controller? The response is not an error so it may be that there is nothing else to describe...

Comment: @strickt01 in that case it should return application name and version but not empty

Comment: I create a new test  web api project and then working. I did nothing, only installed the swagger reference with nuget. I don't now what is wrong with my main project

Comment: @MrBlue Try `http://localhost:56381/swagger/docs/v1` Did you get any result?

Comment: @MegaTron i get error:  <Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>Type 'Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerDocument' with data contract name 'SwaggerDocument:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Swashbuckle.Swagger' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.</ExceptionMessage>

Comment: Now when call the http://localhost:56381/swagger/ui/index, now show this thing: { "statusCode": 200 }.  And when i call http://localhost:56381/swagger/docs/v1 show { "statusCode": 200, "result": { "swagger": "2.0", "info": { "version": "v1", "title": .......}

Comment: I just tried with your configuration and I do not get the error. Can you create a sample project on GitHub that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the tutorial you posted, it looks like somehow your root URL may be different than what swagger expects. From the swagger config file:

> // By default, the service root url is inferred from the request used to access the docs.
>                           // However, there may be situations (e.g. proxy and load-balanced environments) where this does not
>                           // resolve correctly. You can workaround this by providing your own code to determine the root URL.
>                           //
>                           //c.RootUrl(req => GetRootUrlFromAppConfig());

If that is not the case, it could be that the swashbuckle nuget install is somehow corrupted. Try removing the nuget package and reinstalling it.